# How can i find Huawei Ads Publisher Console?

Tags: huawei-mobile-services

I cant find Ad Slot ID.

In my console, i dont see Ads Kit console to create Ad Slot ID.

Please help me to get Ad Slot ID

Comment: What is your huawei developer account type? individual or enterprise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a real ad slot ID, your account type must be an enterprise developer account.

If you only use the ad slot ID for test, use the test ad slot ID.

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/ads-sdk-guide-banner

And if you havean enterprise developer account ,you can click the following links to learn more about advertising monetization:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/monetize/

Answer (score 0):

Ads Publisher Services are not available for Individual Accounts. To access the Ads Publishing console you have to use the Enterprise account.

In the Enterprise account If you are not able to see the Ads Publishing console then make sure you have added the widget from the Customize console option.

[image]